# Radzen Blazor WASM JavaScript Interop function not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, radzen

I am using [**Radzen Blazor Components**](https://blazor.radzen.com/), which are very useful and easy to implement, with a **.NET 6 Blazor WebAssembly App**.

I followed the [guide](https://blazor.radzen.com/get-started) on the Radzen web to install components.

The issue is that I'm trying to call a JavaScript function using IJSRuntime but it throws an Exception saying that the function is undefined. I guess that in some way, the added javascript files are not included in the compilation, because I tested the JS interop with a plain Blazor WASM app and it works.

Can anybody help me? thank you very much.

**Exception:**

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'createAlert' ('createAlert' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'createAlert' ('createAlert' was undefined).
> at https://localhost:7000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:328
> at Array.forEach ()
> at a.findFunction (https://localhost:7000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:296)
> at _ (https://localhost:7000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2437)
> at https://localhost:7000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3325
> at new Promise ()
> at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:7000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3306)
> at Object.St [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost:7000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:59853)
> at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost:7000/_framework/dotnet.6.0.8.yj5vlwdtrc.js:1:195300)
> at wasm://wasm/00971db2:wasm-function[219]:0x1a48f

Here is the code:

**Index.razor**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<RadzenButton Text="Show Alert" Click=@ShowAlert/>

@code {

private async Task ShowAlert() => await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("createAlert");

}
```

**interop.js**

```
function createAlert() {
    alert("Hey this is an alert");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Blazor App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default.css">
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script scr="interop.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IJSObjectReference` to reference JS files:

**Index.razor:**

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<RadzenButton Text="Show Alert" Click=@ShowAlert />

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? moudle;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        moudle = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./interop.js");
    }
    private async Task ShowAlert()
    {
        await moudle.InvokeVoidAsync("createAlert");
    }
}
```

**interop.js:**

```
export function createAlert() {
    alert("Hey this is an alert");
}
```